# Make Generated Word Doc Editable to User

Tags: php

My php script changes the headers to match a word document which the user will download, however, when the user downloads it, it is make read-only. I know the user can manually modify this but I want it to be done from my script itself.
My current headers are:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=License2011.doc");
```

Answer (score 1):

The document will be downloaded by the browser into a temporary location. It is made read-only on purpose to avoid the impression that the user can edit the document, and upload the changes automatically by clicking "Save" (which is the intuitive assumption of everyone not familiar with how HTTP works, and frequently leads to problems when half a day's work they did on a temporary document vanishes forever).

I don't think you can change that "read only" bit on your end. It's up to the browser.

There is, sadly, currently no standards-compliant way to allow a user to download a document, open it in their software, save it, and automatically re-upload it.